Doing Crud operation on google bigquery table using node js
There is a Python backend that generates posts for social media using some AI capabilities. On the frontend (React), I need to render the posts on a calendar. When the user accepts an AI-generated post, I call the Facebook Graph API to schedule the post; otherwise, the user can remove the post.
My problem is that the Python backend stores the data in Google BigQuery. I am fetching the data for each user directly from Google BigQuery. I'm not sure if I should store the data in the local MySQL database that Node.js is using. My goal is to perform CRUD operations on the calendar, but I need to read the data from Google BigQuery. If I store the data in my local MySQL database, I will need to synchronize the data.
How can I achieve this in a way that follows best practices and maintains good performance?

I'm sorry, but I really do not understand your question! BigQuery is a relational database, just like mysql. If you are familiar with mysql, then same concepts apply to BigQuery as well. We can't tell you if storing data in BigQuery or mysql is better for your use case as we know nothing about your business requirements.
